# Simple Pie Chart from table

Tags: r, charts

Let's use an example table:

```
structure(c(2, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 1), .Names = c("Mark", "Greg", 
                                          "Sonya", "Monica", "Tiana", "Arra", "Armin", "Hera", "Cyrus", "Pier", "Tina", "Hector", "Markus"))
```

To each name in this data numbers are assigned. I would like to create a pie chart based on that table. I would like to know how big piece of "cake" belongs to different numbers in the table.

So number `4` is repeated 3 times and that means it will have the biggest percentage/piece of this pie chart. In total we have 13 numbers so `4` represents  23% of pie chart.

I could continue calculating like that and create char manually but that's not a solution for R user. The other problem is that my data is much bigger than presented example...

Additional questions:
Would be great as well if you could show me how to make a chart like the one below:

[image: Example]

Edit:

```
> dput(head(sum_peaks_EOD)
+ )
structure(c(2, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2), .Names = c("AT1G01050", "AT1G01080", 
"AT1G01090", "AT1G01320", "AT1G01470", "AT1G01800"))
```

Comment: did you try `pie(data)`? the second chart is called a barplot `barplot(matrix(data))`

Comment: Yeah, I tried but the problem is that I don't care about names which I have  in the table. The question is only how often numbers from 1 to 8 are found. So my pie chart should be divided only into 8 slices.

Comment: so instead of `data`, you might use `table(data)`

Comment: That's it. I didn't expect that it will be so easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your pie chart:

```
pie(table(dat))
```

For your Histogram, using ggplot2:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dat$factor <-1
ggplot(dat,aes(x=factor,fill=factor(dat))) +
       geom_bar(binwidth=5) +
       coord_flip()
```

EDIT: due to the way the as.data.frame() call works, the column you want to factor will be called the name of the original vector. So, if your data is called sum_peaks_EOD:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(sum_peaks_EOD)
dat$factor <-1
ggplot(dat,aes(x=factor,fill=factor(sum_peaks_EOD))) +
           geom_bar(binwidth=5) +
           coord_flip()
```

Comment: Histogram works well for example data but using my original one I get this error: `Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?`

Comment: You probably have a list rather than a vector - can you call dput() on your data and edit the question?

Comment: Is it possible to add a scale from 0 to 100 as in the picture I posted in the question ?

Comment: ggplot(dat,aes(x=factor,fill=factor(sum_peaks_EOD))) +
  geom_bar(binwidth=5,aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100)) +
  coord_flip()